# Magento2 Token not generating

Tags: magento2, api, soap, soap-api-v2

I am trying to generate a token which i need to create a **WEB SERVICE** for which i am using following code but i am not able to get a token.

Can any one please suggest me the proper way to generate a token.

```
<?php
$adminUrl='http://magento2-dev.local/index.php/rest/V1/integration/admin/token';
$ch = curl_init();
$data = array("username" => "admin", "password" => "password");
$data_string = json_encode($data);
$ch = curl_init($adminUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))
);
$token = curl_exec($ch);
$token=  json_decode($token);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($token);
exit;
?>
```

Comment: Is the token id not coming in the curl response ?

I tried your code and the token is coming in my curl response.

Can you check your `oauth_token` table (token feild) and see if any record is present there.

Comment: table is blank, when i check for OAuth module in my phpinfo, it is not available. will it require for this?

Comment: Ok, make sure that the host entry for the virtual host of the application is present in the host file, sometimes curl doesnot working if the host entry is not proper

Comment: Thanks Atish it works for me now please update the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes it happens that the host entry of the virtual host created for the project is missing in the host file.

You can check by pinging the virtual host and see if you get a response.

```
→  ping magento2-dev.local
ping: unknown host magento2-dev.local
```

If you get a response like ***unknown host*** make sure that the host entry is present in the hosts file of the system.

If you are using windows they should be present at `C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts`

[image]

> Make sure the notepad (or any text editor) you are using is opened with administrator privileges **(Run as Administrator)**

If you are using a UNIX (MAC or Linux) system they should be at `/etc/hosts`

```
sudo vi /etc/hosts
```

> Make sure the notepad (or any text editor) you are using is opened with superuser privileges **(run as root)**

In the file add a new line with the local ip and virtual host name

```
[local ip]<space>[virtual host name]

127.0.0.1 magento2-dev.local
```

Once the entry is added and saved you can test out by, pinging the virtual host again and if everything is working proper you should get an output like this:

```
→  ping magento2-dev.local
PING magento2-dev (127.0.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from orion (127.0.1.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.032 ms
64 bytes from orion (127.0.1.1): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.042 ms
64 bytes from orion (127.0.1.1): icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.041 ms
64 bytes from orion (127.0.1.1): icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.038 ms
64 bytes from orion (127.0.1.1): icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=0.040 ms
64 bytes from orion (127.0.1.1): icmp_seq=6 ttl=64 time=0.043 ms
64 bytes from orion (127.0.1.1): icmp_seq=7 ttl=64 time=0.043 ms
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
//Authentication rest API magento2.Please change url accordingly your url
$adminUrl='http://localhost/magentoce27/index.php/rest/V1/integration/admin/token';
$ch = curl_init();
$data = array("username" => "productuser", "password" => "productuser123");                                                                   
$data_string = json_encode($data);                   
$ch = curl_init($adminUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                                  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))                                                                       
);       
$token = curl_exec($ch);
$token=  json_decode($token);   

//print_r($token);

//Use above token into header
$headers = array("Authorization: Bearer $token"); 


$requestUrl='http://localhost/magentoce27/index.php/rest/V1/products/24-MB01';

/*Unauthorized access for this productuser for customers details*/
//$requestUrl = 'http://localhost/magentoce26/index.php/rest/V1/customers/2';
/*End*/

$ch = curl_init();
$ch = curl_init($requestUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  

$result = curl_exec($ch);
$result=  json_decode($result);
print_r($result);
?>
```

I have used above script and put this script in my magento root folder. it does show me output for requested url product.

Comment: doesn't work for me